# Ways to confirm 4K Netflix video playback on macos safari browser

Tags: macos, mac, safari, 4k-resolution, netflix

I was finding ways to confirm that Netflix videos are streaming at 4K frame rate because it seems they somenhow don't show the "Ultra HD 4K" icon when displaying on monitors even though 4K playback is supported.

I used to be able to open a menu by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> during playback, where I can check that the bitrate is 3840x2160, hence confirming that it is playing back with 4K resolution.

However I found that the command is no longer working. The menu does not show up anymore even when entered during playback.

Any idea on how to reenable the menu, or are there any ways to confirm that Netflix videos are playing back with 4K resolution on Safari browser?

Answer (score 0):

I finally realise the command was incorrect, it should be <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>, which will show the Netflix menu. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean Ctrl+Cmd+Opt+Shift+D

Answer (score 0):

It's

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>